# Filtering and Sorting Products in Django Oscar ? In-built feature or have to custom build?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Not a programming question per se, more of a feature question. I was trying Django-Oscar and find it great. Is there in-built way to filter the products by categories?

And also is there in-built way to sort products by prices? I can build it myself, was just asking in-case already some feature is available. I tried reading its docs : http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/. Nothing much I found.

Comment: filtering products is built-in, the docs aren't clear at all... to enable it you need to install Solr http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_setup_solr.html?highlight=solr

Comment: can i set up `solr` locally ? or in deployed version only ? This line in docs I don't understand `ln -s <your_oscar_checkout>/sites/<sandbox|demo>/deploy/solr conf`

Comment: yes I'm running Solr locally... to use the example conf from Oscar (definitely easiest way) you need to install Solr 4 rather than v5 ...if on OSX the simplest way is with homebrew `brew tap homebrew/versions` `brew install solr4`

Comment: @Coderaemon did you solve this problem? how did you replace the `<your_oscar_checkout>` part? Should it be the path to the containing package like `/home/user/django-oscar` or to a particular file?

Comment: @SaketMishra the answer worked. In brief. Download solr and django-oscar (full version which has sites/demo folders). Now just make a soft link from demo/deploy/solr folder(in django oscar, you can copy it to your project folder) to the downloaded solr's conf, like this. `ln -s django-oscar/sites/demo/deploy/solr ~/Downloads/solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install Solr 4. eg on OSX you could:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew install solr4
```

(has to be Solr 4 in order to use the ready-made conf from Oscar)

Then get a copy of the Oscar source code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.git
```

Then replace the conf in the Solr example site (what the Solr server serves by default) with a symlink to the Solr conf included with the Oscar demo site, roughly as per the Oscar docs [here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_setup_solr.html)

First find your Solr install:

```
$ brew info solr4
homebrew/versions/solr4: stable 4.10.4
Enterprise search platform from Apache Lucene project
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/
Conflicts with: solr
/usr/local/Cellar/solr4/4.10.4 (4658 files, 248M) *
  Built from source
```

Then have a look, here is where I've symlinked the conf:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/solr4/4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/
total 24
-rw-r--r--   1 me  wheel  2146  8 Sep  2014 README.txt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  wheel    44  7 Jun 13:37 conf -> <path to oscar repo>/sites/demo/deploy/solr
drwxr-xr-x  24 me  wheel   816 27 Feb  2015 conf.original
-rw-r--r--   1 me  wheel    16  8 Sep  2014 core.properties
drwxr-xr-x   4 me  wheel   136  6 Jun 17:03 data
```